# a problem with complex numbers that may have a geometric solution

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

**The statement of the problem** : For a strictly positive real number **r** and **z** $\in \mathbb C$, we consider the set : $D_z(r) =  \{ v \in \mathbb C \,|\,  |z-v|\leq r \}$ .  We also consider the following notation for any subset $A,B \subset \mathbb C$ , $A+B = \{ a + b \,|\, a \in A, b \in B \}$.

Let $r$ and $s$ be 2 strictly positive real numbers and $z$ and $u$ 2 complex numbers. Prove that $D_z(r) $ + $D_u(s) $ = $D_{z+u}(r+s) $.

**My approach** : I tried for a while to prove the relationship using the algebraic form of the complex numbers, but I ran into some *ugly* calculations, so I gave up. I think that the solution to this problem involves the consideration of some circles in a complex plane, but I don't really have any ideas where to start.

Any and all proofs will be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $D_z(r) + D_u(s)\subset D_{z + u}(r + s)$ follows from the inequality
$$
|z + u - (v + w)|\leq |z - v| + |u - w|\leq r + s
$$
where $v\in D_z(r)$ and $w\in D_u(s)$.

Now, suppose $v\in D_{z + u}(r + s)$. Take $w = r\frac{v - u}{r + s} + \frac{sz}{r + s}$ and notice that
\begin{align}
|z - w| &= \left|z - r\frac{v - u}{r + s} - \frac{sz}{r + s}\right|\\
&= \left|\frac{r}{r + s}(z + u - v)\right|\\
&\leq \frac{r}{r+s}(r+s)\\
&= r
\end{align}
which means that $w\in D_z(r)$. Also, notice that taking $h = s\frac{v - z}{r + s} + \frac{ru}{r + s}$, we have by an  analoguous calculation that $h\in D_u(s)$. To finish the argument, one just need to verify that $v = w + h$, which proves that $D_{z + u}(r + s)\subset D_z(r) + D_u(s)$.